# I was coding a music bot for me and my friends when i found this error

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

The error was -> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'VoiceState' object has no attribute 'play'

Here is the code that gave me the error

```
 vc = ctx.author.voice
    if vc:
        await vc.channel.connect()

        vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(f"{video_info['title']}.mp3"))
```

I searched through stackoverflow to find the answer, but nothing was working .

Comment: From the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html) (worth consulting if you're just starting out using the API) it looks like you'd instead want to do `client = await vc.channel.connect(); client.play(...)` ✌

Comment: @msbit Thanks! I tried it out but it just freezes with a message saying "Updating container for {mp3 file}" I think its an error of FFmpeg and ill figure it out eventually.